# Rails: Pre-Populating form in edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a complex assessment form which has many questions and questions have many answers. I'm submitting the form manually via Javascript but having issues populating the data in the Edit view.

I'm not getting an error but all the fields are blank:

```
<%= form_for @assessment do |f| %>
  ...
    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
        <%= question.content %>

        <%= builder.fields_for :answers do |f| %>
            ....
        <% end %>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Controller Action:

```
 def edit
    @assessment = current_user.assessments.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Models:

```
Assessment.rb
 has_many :questions, :through=> :template
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers

Question.rb
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers

Answer.rb
 belongs_to :assessment
  belongs_to :question
```

Where is my mistake? All actions are working exactly as I want them (new, create, show, delete). Only action I'm having with is Edit/Update.

Comment: show the full error log please

Comment: Hey - sorry had wrong title before. There's actually no error, but my fields aren't populating

Comment: read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

Comment: in your assassment.rb file change nested_attributes do be accepted for :questions, not :answers

Comment: Please post your `update`  and your `assessment_params` methods